# Extend & Search Native WordPress Image Galleries With Tags and Taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, search, tags, media

How can I tag, taxonomize and search native media?

I believe my obstacle is my failure to think "the WordPress way".

Building my own plugin or theme code, I am looking to achieve the following results:

1. Tag and taxonomize media in the native WordPress media library.
2. Allow for searching of that media by it's taxonomy/tag/title/description.

Should I be thinking custom post type?